# Code coverage for service call success response in karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a function like this

```
$scope.openMail=function(mail){
      DocumentTypes.getDocument(function(response){
          $scope.documentTypes=response.result;
          $log.log("documentTypes",$scope.documentTypes);
          })
}
```

Spec for above fun is

```
it("should test open mail", function(){
    scope.documentTypes=[{"type":"pdf"},{"type":"xml"}];
    spyOn(documentTypes,"getDocument").and.callFake(function(){
      return scope.documentTypes;
    });
    var mail='back';
    scope.openMail(mail);
    expect(scope.documentTypes).toEqual({"type":"pdf"},{"type":"xml"});


  })
```

so the code is not covering for `function(response){}`

[image: so the code is not covering code for <code>function(response){}</code>]
How can i cover this code in my code coverage? Thanks.

Comment: your test is red or green?

Comment: How is `DocumentTypes` being injected in you test? Also, since you are spying on the function, can you try adding `expect(documentTypes.getDocument).toHaveBeenCalled()` and see if it actually gets called during the test run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems with your test:

1. You do `spyOn(documentTypes,"getDocument")` instead of `spyOn(DocumentTypes,"getDocument")`
2. Your fake function returns a value (synchronous) rather than call the provided callback (asynchronous)
3. You start off by initializing `scope.documentTypes` to the expected result of the test, i.e. the test passes no matter what the code does (unless you get an exception)
4. More of a problem with your code - The function you're testing does nothing with the input `mail` parameter

Here's how I would test it:

```
describe('$scope.openMail', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        spyOn(DocumentTypes, 'getDocument');
    });

    it('uses DocumentTypes.getDocument service to get the document types', function() {
        $scope.openMail('test_mail');

        expect(DocumentTypes.getDocument).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function));
    });

    describe('provides a callback function that', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            DocumentTypes.getDocument.and.callFake(function (callback) {
                callback('test_document_types');
            });
        });

        it('stores the document types on the scope', function() {           
            $scope.openMail('test_mail');

            expect($scope.documentTypes).toEqual('test_document_types');
        });

        // Note: This is optional, depending on whether you test logging or not
        it('logs the document types', function() {           
            spyOn($log, 'log');

            $scope.openMail('test_mail');

            expect($log.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('documentTypes', 'test_document_types');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank u very much, It's working.
can u suggest for a service call which has parameter like following way

`EmailStatus.unlockEmailStatus({"emailStatusDetail":unlockEmailStatusDetail},function(response){ $log.log("updateUnlockEmailStatus",response); `

Comment: Thank u very much, It's working.
can u suggest a testcase for a service call which has parameter like following way

`EmailStatus.unlockEmailStatus({"emailStatusDetail":unlockEmailStatusDetail},function(response){ $log.log("updateUnlockEmailStatus",response); 
});`

Comment: What are you trying to test exactly ? The `unlockEmailStatus` function ?

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally wrong here, but if that call to DocumentTypes.getDocument(...) is an async call you may need to trigger a digest cycle by calling `scope.apply()` just after you call `scope.openMail(mail)`

Comment: we tried `scope.$apply()` but there is no change in code coverage

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are injecting DocumentTypes into your controller or whatever you have that openMail function in, you can mock it when performing tests. One way of doing that could be to use the $provide service.

This mock could look like this if using karma-chai-spies:

```
stubs = {
    DocumentTypes: {
        getDocument: chai.spy(function(callback)
        {
            callback({
                result: [
                    "type"
                ]
            });
        })
    }
};
```

Then provide it using $provide in your unit tests:

```
beforeEach(function()
{
    module(function($provide)
    {
        $provide.value("DocumentTypes", stubs.DocumentTypes);
    });
});
```

The test itself could then look something like this using karma-mocha and karma-chai:

```
it("should test open mail", function()
{
    var controller = $controller('myController', {
        $scope: stubs.$scope
    });

    stubs.$scope.openMail("mail");

    expect(stubs.$scope.documentTypes).to.deep.equal([
        "type"
    ]);
    expect(stubs.DocumentTypes.getDocument).to.have.been.called.once();
});
```